# My file has not been modified. Why is Git still telling me it has been changed

Tags: ios, xcode, git, macos

Now whenever I click on a file in Xcode without making any changes to the file, a change record is generated in Git. Why is this happening?

1.So in Xcode, I click on the file ChangePhoneMessageCodeView.h
2.Then, I executed "git status"

```
xxxMacBook-Pro smartProject % git status
    On branch master
    Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
    
    Untracked files:
      (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        ._ smartProject.xcodeproj
        ._ smartProject.xcworkspace
        Pods/._Pods.xcodeproj
        Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/xxx.xcuserdatad/
        smartProject.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/xxx.xcuserdatad/
        smartProject.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/xxx.xcuserdatad/
        smartProject/._ChangePhoneMessageCodeView.h
        smartProject/._ChangePhoneMessageCodeView.m
```

3.Then, I executed git diff
but,there's nothing to show

Comment: This output means nothing changed. The files it listed out is the untracked files, which means they are new files.

Comment: The code of the remote warehouse is the same as that of the local warehouse. These files are not new added, but when I click the file, there will be an untracked record in Git @ElapsedSoul

Comment: Cloning the project to another computer is fine. However, whenever I click on a project file on my current computer, Git will show a record, but I haven't modified the project file.

Comment: The files are prefix with '.' which means it's a shawdow file. So you see it's the same,it just you can not see them at all, but git do not cheat us. These files prefix with '._' seems some securety software to record you action or a cache for the files not store to disk like office do on windows. So it might be an other problem which have nothing to do with git.

Comment: The new files are generated by event you clicked the file. Then ```git status``` show you the untracked files which are also not staged status. ```git diff``` command is showing the difference between staged code and commited code on current branch HEAD.In your case nothing to shown is correct. So your problem is it's who generate the files when you click the file file.

Comment: I agree with you. I decided to reinstall Xcode

Comment: Reinstall will not help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like those files are generated by XCode, and they have to be added to `.gitignore` file. Example of such `.gitignore` file could be found here - https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Xcode.gitignore.

So, add and commit `.gitignore` file to repository, and update it in a way that it will include files/folders which you do not need to track in your repository.

Comment: I added the.gitignore file, but it didn't work

Comment: @jiaoxiaker, what content do you have in `.gitignore`? Does it contain files which are shown as "untracked" now?

Comment: No, It doesn't contain.Xcode generates the file 'smartProject/._ChangePhoneMessageCodeView.h' when I click on the file.Use the SourceTree to see how this file compares before and after
Before: 'smartProject /._ ChangePhoneMessageCodeView. h
After: 'smartProject_ /. _ChangePhoneMessageCodeView. h
I don't know why there is such a change.

Comment: @jiaoxiaker, if you did not include those files to gitignore - how do you expect then .gitignore would help you? It is no enough just to add .gitignore file, it should have list of files/folders which you do not want to track in git. If XCode generates temporary files - add those files to .gitignore, that's the point.

Comment: This is the file I want to track, but the problem is that I haven't modified the file, just click on it and Git generates a record

Comment: No, file "._ChangePhoneMessageCodeView.h" and "ChangePhoneMessageCodeView.h" which you click on - are apparently different files. Check full path to file on which you click, and file which is shown as "untracked". Please, post here full path to file on which you click on.

Comment: xxxMacBook-Pro SmartProject % ls -a
.     Info.plist
..     ChangePhoneMessageCodeView.h
._AppDelegate.h    ChangePhoneMessageCodeView.m
._AppDelegate.m    Main
._ChangePhoneMessageCodeView.h Resource
._ChangePhoneMessageCodeView.m

Comment: Yes, it's not the same file, I don't understand why clicking on this file “ ChangePhoneMessageCodeView.h”will generate it  "._ChangePhoneMessageCodeView.h"

Comment: @jiaoxiaker - because this is how XCode works. It does not matter for you indeed, just take it as a fact. XCode uses those temporary files for its needs - how does that influence your work flow? Now you know that temporary files should be ignored by git, so go ahead please, add them to gitignore, and that's it.